# Change the format of the output results in F# interactive

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

Can I change the format of the output result which is returned when I call the variable name in FSI windows?

I overrided the `ToString()` function in my object, but it does not affect the output results in FSI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use the `fsi.AddPrinter` function to add a printer for your type.

Comment: Don Syme wrote a blog on this recently: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2010/01/08/some-tips-and-tricks-for-formatting-data-in-f-interactive-and-a-in-sprintf-printf-fprintf.aspx